# Indexing a matrix by a column vector

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix M of size m x n, and column vector of m x 1.
For each of m rows, I need to pickup the index corresponding to the value in the column vector minus 1. Thus, giving me answer m x 1. How can I do this?

```
zb=a1.a3[np.arange(a1.z3.shape[0]),a1.train_labels-1]

zb.shape
Out[72]: (4000, 4000)

a1.z3.shape
Out[73]: (4000, 26)

a1.train_labels.shape
Out[74]: (4000, 1)

a1.train_labels.head()
Out[75]: 
      22
1618  25
2330   1
1651  17
133   17
2360   5


#my column vector a1.train_labels is shuffled. I don't want to unshuffle it.
```

Answer (score 1):

If your 2d array is *M*, and indices are a 1d array `v`, then you can use

```
M[np.arange(len(v)), v - 1]
```

For example:

```
In [14]: M = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

In [15]: v = np.array([2, 1])

In [16]: M[np.arange(len(v)), v - 1]
Out[16]: array([2, 3])
```

Comment: It doesn't work as shown in my example. Try shuffling the column vector `random_perm=np.random.permutation(data_size) train_labels=train_labels.iloc[random_perm]`

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia On my example it works after using `np.random.permutation`, so I think the problem is where you're transforming the things into `numpy` arrays (from there it seems to work). Could you either post the exact error message you're getting, or some minimal self-contained example? (preferably both).